# Docker: Accessing to a mysql container from another container in same host (No route to host error)

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, iptables

I have a virtual machine with this IP: `10.23.23.23`
On this VM, Docker is running and 2 containers are created:

- **Container1 (Apache running)** : This container exposes the port `13080` and bin the port `80` of apache inside the container
- **Container2 (mysql)** : This container exposes the port `5555` and bind the port `3306` of mysql inside the container.

In Container1, i am trying to access to container2, but i get the following error: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No route to host`

Notes:

The following command on VM host:

```
ip addr show docker0
```

returns:

```
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP
    link/ether 02:42:cf:7e:ea:b7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::41:cfff:fe7e:eab7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What can i do to be able to join the second container (mysql) from the first one ?

Comment: Please include the commands/config you use to start each container, and the hostname/port you are using inside of container1 to reach container2.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be `IP:PORT` exposing issue. If you want to refer containers using host IP make sure mysql is listening on all the IPs i.e `0.0.0.0` in the container and then give it a try using host ports.

Normally these issues occur when services in the container are running at `localhost/127.0.0.1`.